# How do I make a contenteditable='false' div have the same height as a contenteditable='true'?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that's been used as an "input" by using `contenteditable`, and it works great when it is enabled. But there's one scenario where I need to disable the "input" by setting `contenteditable='false'`, which makes the div lose its height (as you can see in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5c7fo9c/)).

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="visible-borders"></div>
<div contenteditable="false" class="visible-borders"></div>
```

Do you guys have any solution to that? I wanted something that didn't involve `min-height`. And no, I cannot change the code to use something other than `contenteditable`. I'm using someone else's code.

Comment: This only happens when the `div` is empty (unlike the `contenteditable` version, which leaves space for text entry). Can you add text, even `&nbsp;` to the non-editable `div`? https://jsfiddle.net/a5c7fo9c/2/

Comment: Yes, only when it's empty. I can't, it's someone else's component. What I can do is overwrite the CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `contenteditable=false` div has no content and nothing holding it open, whereas the content-editable element has default styling that shows its editable (specifically: `-webkit-user-modify: read-write`)

You could simply give the `.visible-borders` a min-height. If (for some unspecified reason) you don't want to use min-height, you could insert some pseudo content:

```
.visible-borders:before {
    content: "\00a0"
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a5c7fo9c/6/

Comment: Read OP: I wanted something that didn't involve min-height

Answer (score 5):

You can use pseudo elements

**CSS**

```
.visible-borders {
    border: solid 1px black;
    display:block;

}
.visible-borders:after {
    content:"\00a0";
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a5c7fo9c/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can include "empty" (zero-width, invisible) pseudo-content in the `contenteditable=false` version:

```css
.visible-borders {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.visible-borders[contenteditable=false]:after {
  content: "\200B";   /* zero-width space */
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="visible-borders"></div>
<br />
<div contenteditable="false" class="visible-borders"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the contenteditable attribute leaves a space for the text to be written, if you want the to be equal pick any height larger than the space required to write a line of text, and there is not need for contenteditable=false because it's the default in html when it's not specified !